# How to get the object containing the latest LocalDate inside a hashmap

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

I have a properties inside the DVDs object called `releaseDate` and its a `String`.

`getReleaseDateFormatted()` is a method inside my DVDs object where I would parse a `String` to `LocalDate`.

I assume the following code would group all the `releaseDate` together in `LocalDate` type? I need to find the latest date inside this group.

```
@Override
public DVDs getOldestDVD() throws PersistenceException {
    return dvdMap.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d getReleaseDateFormatted()))                
}
```

Comment: This is a confusing question. It would help if you included some more context.

Comment: Why are you assuming? Why don't you test your code?

Comment: what I mean by latest is.  If I have two dvds, one released by 02/02/2017, and one by 12/02/2016.  I want it to return former.

Comment: That makes sense, but that's the opposite meaning of "oldest".

Comment: Why do you have a class named `DVDs`? How many DVDs does an instance represent?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: What type does `getReleaseDateFormatted()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very vague and confusing, but if my understanding is correct, you shouldn't need any streams. Try this:

```
return Collections.max(dvdMap.values(),
        Comparator.comparing(DVDs::getReleaseDateFormatted));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: But, of course, you *can* also use `dvdMap.values().stream().max(…)` instead of `Collections.max(dvdMap.values(), …)`, if you prefer.